# How to set ionic checkbox selected only one?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

How can only set it only can be select one checkbox only? //below image show current can be select multi checkbox.

```
//html
<td><ion-checkbox :value="item.cCouponCode" @ionChange="GetCode($event)" checked="false"></ion-checkbox></td>
```

```
//typescript
GetCode($event){
this.SelectedVoucherCode = $event.detail.value;
console.log($event);
}
```

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 0):

By adding an ID the elements when doing the loop. Each of those items need an id attached to be able to target specific item.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer

```
//typescript
if(this.SelectedList.length >=1){
        $event.target.checked = false;
        alert('You cant selected more than one voucher/ '+ 'You already selected'+this.SelectedList[0].Code);
}
else{
    this.SelectedList.push({'Code':$event.detail.value});
}
```

```
//html
<ion-checkbox :value="item.cCouponCode" @ionChange="GetCode($event)" checked="false" :id="index">
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `ion-radio-group` and `ion-radio` for this task as the requisite is that only one of the rows can be selected:

```xml
<ion-radio-group :value="selection">
  <td v-for="item in items">
    <ion-radio :value="item.cCouponCode" />
  </td>
</ion-radio-group>
```

And declare `selection` in your script's data section so its value is updated reactively.

See `ion-radio` docs here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio